# I can't find Virtualization on my Bios menu

Tags: bios, virtualization, vt-x

My laptop Toshiba Satellite AMD-A8

I checked the features of this processor and learned that virtualization is supported on this processor.
But I can't find it in BIOS settings

Is there any way I can enable virtualization?

Comment: Unfortunately, some devices lack the required firmware (BIOS/UEFI) support for virtualization, even if all hardware supports it otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

As your laptop uses an AMD CPU the option is usually called "SVM" in stead of virtualization.
(Usually found under "Advanced->CPU settings", but that can vary greatly from one bios to the next.)

As binary_jam already mentioned in the other answer. If the setting is not available in Bios there is NO WAY it can be enabled, unless you can find a Bios update that adds that setting.

Unfortunately some computer manufacturers seem to think virtualization is only for "business" users and they simply don't give you the choice on their consumer models.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, some laptop manufacturers don't include the option to enable/disable the CPUs virtualization capabilities in their BIOS/UEFI firmware.

If you don't find the option in the BIOS/UEFI settings, chances are very slim to find a different way of enabling it. That option however would be specific to the very model you own.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes virtualization is permanently enabled. The BIOS (actually UEFI) setup may lack an option to toggle it, but it doesn't mean it doesn't work.

You can check if it's available in Windows Task Manager on the *Performance* tab. Select CPU in the left pane and look for *Virtualization* in the right one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I will look at the settings you say